# Swift Firebase Function Return

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a hard time with Firebase values in return functions. This seems to be an ongoing problem for me. I have written up a basic example of my issue. How do I go about doing this?

```
func getChartIndexValues(completion:@escaping (Double) -> ()) {

    //Firebase Initialization
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("general_room_index").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        var zero = snapDict?["0"] as! Double

        completion(zero)
        })

}


   returnFunction() -> (Double) {

      getChartIndexValues() { (zero) -> () in

            let testValue = zero
        }


     return //THis is my problem
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hinted at your problem, but not stated it explicitly. The deal is that you can't return the result of an async function as a function result. You need to pass in a completion handler that runs when the function finishes, and that code is the code that has access to the result.

```
returnFunction() -> (Double) {

  getChartIndexValues() { (zero) -> () in

    //Your code to process the results belongs here
    self.someInstanceVar = zero
    someLabel.text = "Your result is \(zero)"
    }

}
//You CAN'T put your code to process results here.
```

Comment: So what your saying is i cant by-pass the block to return a value in a function? I have to assign it to a label or whatever I want to assign it to?